# Simple sql regarding select into (copy a single column from another table into an empty one with multiple columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got two tables:

```
TABLE A (columns: FirstValue, SecondValue, SeatNumber)

currently empty

TABLE B(1 column: SeatNumber)

Contains 300 rows with different numbers.
```

How do I populate TABLE A so that FirstValue and SecondValue are '1' and '2' respectively, but the SeatNumber is populated from TABLE B?
I'm assuming this can be done using "select into".

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO A (FirstValue, SecondValue, SeatNumber)
SELECT 1,
       2,
       SeatNumber
  FROM B
```

Comment: I knew it was simple. Thanks @Nitin!

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into A(FirstValue, SecondValue, SeatNumber)
select '1', '2', SeatNumber 
     from B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA (FirstValue, SecondValue, SeatNumber) 
SELECT
  '1',
  '2',
  SeatNumber
FROM
   TABLEB
```

Hope this Helps!!